# Finish entire loop / forEach before next command

Tags: node.js, firebase, loops, foreach, google-cloud-functions

I had this working until I added a few more commands after the forEach. Basically when a post gets deleted the primary goal is to remove it from user's feeds (which was working). I then chained the 4 .then() and now it is only looping once then completes the rest of the processes... How can I make sure it loops then entire collection before it continues?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    exports.updateFeedDelete = functions.database.ref('/categories/{postId}')
      .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

      //...

      const followersRef = admin.database().ref(`friends/${friendId}`);

      return followersRef.once("value", function(snap) {
        snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          const followerId = childSnapshot.key;
          //FINISH ALL LOOPS HERE?
          return admin.database().ref(`feed/${followerId}/${postId}`).remove();
        });
      })
      //DONT EXECUTE UNTIL ALL LOOPS ARE DONE, NOT ONLY 1...
      .then(() => {
        //...
      })
      .then(() => {
        //...
      })
      .then(() => {
        //...
      })
      .then(() => {
        //...
    })
```

I appreciate all the help I can get with this, Cheers!

Comment: In this case it would be cleaner to use await/async.

Comment: Add async at the back of callback function inside snap.forEach loop and look if it helps

Comment: [Promise.all() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks I made my code as minimal as I could. Promise.all() is hard to wrap my head around for this. Would you be able to give me a minimal example?

Comment: @mzparacha Hello, are you saying add async instead of function, then would I have to replace return with await? only for the forEach loop? Cheers.

Comment: @user202729 For the whole thing?

Comment: @mzparacha - `.forEach()` does not wait for an `async` callback.  Not sure how that helps with anything.

Comment: @mzparacha I just dont understand what you said at first

Comment: don't use `snap.forEach`, use `Promise.all` around `snap.map(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know when a whole bunch of parallel operations are done, use the promise interface on your database to get a promise for each operation and use `Promise.all()` to monitor an array of promises and tell you when they are all done and then start the rest of your code when `Promise.all()` tells you everything is done.

I don't really know the firebase API, but from a little poking around in the doc, I think it could look something like this:

```
exports.updateFeedDelete = functions.database.ref('/categories/{postId}')
  .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

  //...

  const followersRef = admin.database().ref(`friends/${friendId}`);

  return followersRef.once("value").then(snap => 
    let promises = [];
    snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      const followerId = childSnapshot.key;
      // do whatever else here.  If asynchronous, chain promises
      // so you're pushing one promise into the array that
      // represents when all this code is done
      promises.push(admin.database().ref(`feed/${followerId}/${postId}`).remove());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);                                     
  }).then(() => {
    // code here will run after the snap.forEach() code is done
  }).catch(err => {
    // handle errors here
  });
})
```

Comment: I am using forEach because of firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#for-each

Comment: @hugger - OK, I added a code example, that gives you a general idea how you would use `Promise.all()` to track when all the async operations in your `.forEach()` iteration loop are done.

Comment: @hugger if ordering matters, use orderBy instead of simply relying on forEach.That said, `.map` works exactly the same as `forEach`, which means you can wrap it in Promise.all and "wait for everything to finish" without having to run everything one by one.

Comment: `forEach` just to `push` each into an array would be cleaner as a `map`

Comment: @jfriend00 This works like a charm, thanks a lot my man. order does not matter because they're all getting deleted at the same time.

Comment: @AjahnCharles - Keep in mind, this isn't `array.forEach()`.  It's a firebase API `snapshot.forEach()`.  As I said in my answer, I am just reading the firebase API from for the first time myself, so I'll go see if firebase offers a `.map()` themselves.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Good spot! Might be something like `snapshot.data()` to get an array. For sure I have mapped the results of firestore queries before in JS.

Comment: @AjahnCharles - It might be `.val()` to get an array.  Fortunately, this works for the OP so I won't attempt to modify it any more.  Plus, it is generally better to iterate database results rather than stuff them all into an array, just to iterate them as its more efficient (when qty is large) when you don't need them all at one time.